# Destruction via const iterators in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

Take 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase
for an example. Why have the signatures changed from using non-const iterators to const-iterators given that the operation does modify the container via the supplied iterator?

I thought that was the definition of what non-const iterators were for. What is the reasoning behind the change?

Comment: The constness of an iterator pertains to the container *element*, not to the container itself. Consider `{ const int a = 1; }` There's no conceptual trouble with the destruction of `a` at the end of the scope, is there?

Comment: @Kerrek SB But std::vector::erase doesn't necessarily have to destroy the targets. It may overwrite them as well.

Comment: That's true, but the container's requirements on insertablity of elements means that there's no observable difference.

Comment: You can read some of the reasoning in the proposal for the change: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2350.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only do the `erase` if you already have non-const access to the container (`erase` is a non-const member function).

Given that, you could already convert your `const_iterator` to an `iterator` (possibly inefficiently using `distance` and `advance`), so you are not getting any extra access.

Answer (score 1):

An iterator being const means that the element the iterator is pointing to cannot be modified through that iterator. This does not mean that the container itself can't modify those contents using the iterator's information.

Comment: @PSkocik And if you pass two pointers to a function, one const and one non-const, if they both point to subobjects of the same complete object, the function can modify the pointee of the const pointer by dereferencing the non-const pointer.